# ng-options to work with response from promise

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving a promise like so.

```
      GetAgentsPromise.then(function(response) {
            GetAgentsPromise.then(function(response) {
                $scope.ClientAgents.id =  response.data.d.AgentIDs;
                $scope.ClientAgents.name = response.data.d.FullNames;
                console.log($scope.ClientAgents); 
            })      
        });
```

My select looks like so

```
 <select ng-model="ClientAgents">
                        <option ng-repeat="ClientAgent in ClientAgents" value="ClientAgent.id" id="SortTypeSelect" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" style="width: 70%;">{{ClientAgent.name}}</option>
                    </select>
```

What am I doing wrong and why ?

My response is returning the correct data.

[My array looks like this](https://snag.gy/HyP6l.jpg)

[image]

Comment: What do the console.log show in the console ?

Comment: if you want to bind ClientAgent id then you to pass that in value like this `value={{ClientAgent.id}}` or `ng-value="ClientAgent.id"`

Comment: @Okazari it shows an object with two property's an id array and a name array

Comment: Am i going to have to iterate the response object and construct an object or array ? Because it seems like i shouldn't have to write code to manually do that.

Comment: @Anik Islam Abhi  I have updated my question with what my response object looks like

Comment: I changed my response object to work with angular, I now return an Array of objects with id and name property's. Instead of returning one object with two arrays containing ids and names respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `ng-value` to bind value with `ng-model`

Check this [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lytuj10h5DwUCYrcRFXk?p=preview)

Select-Option :

```
<select ng-model="ClientAgent">
    <option ng-value="ClientAgent.id" ng-repeat="ClientAgent in ClientAgents" id="SortTypeSelect" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" style="width: 70%;">{{ClientAgent.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This will bind it if i make my object an array of objects. But it displays the whole name array. Not each property  within the object.

Comment: I will accept this but i just changed my response object to instead of returning two arrays, to return an array of objects with id and name property's. That bound correctly.